# Creating PDF in iOS: Lines and Rectangles

Tags: ios, pdf

I already created some PDF under iOS mainly using [NSString drawAtPoint].

My Question is: How can I draw lines and rectangles?
And how can I draw a grey colored box/frame as a background layer to include text in it?

EDIT: Ok, I found something regarding drawing rectangles: renderInContext.
Nevertheless this code:

`UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 240, 300, 150)];

[lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[[lbl layer] renderInContext:currentContext];`

is drawing the UILabel with the right width/height but at the wrong origins (0, 0)!
Any idea why?

Comment: Use `UIBezierPath` instances to draw lines or any other shapes that can be filled or stroked.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.raywenderlich.com/6581/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1 and http://www.raywenderlich.com/6818/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2 for some examples.

Comment: Not exactly what I looked for, but a good start. I'm closing this question to start a new more specific one.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: because that's how `renderInContext:` works -- it draws your layer(-tree) in the current context at the context's current position ((0,0) by default.)

If you think in terms of the graphics context being the table below, and you have a **fixed, immovable** piece of cardboard with a [square] cutout on the table, and you draw in the cutout, the thing you want to do is *move the table* (the context) underneath, in order to draw in the desired location.

You do that with `CGContextTranslateCTM`.  So, for your label above, the code would look something like this:

**(WARNING**: Code typed in browser, not checked for perfect accuracy.)

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -100, -240);  // Note how you're moving /negative/ because you're moving the table, not the cardboard.
[[lbl layer] renderInContext:currentContext];
```

Good luck!

Comment: It's only 2 yrs old to *you*!  To the ***next*** guy looking for the same answer, it's brand-new.  :)